# Dynamically-Sized List of Fields in Yesod

Tags: forms, haskell, web, yesod

In HTML, multiple fields can be specified with a non-unique name like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" value="eggs">
<input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" value="bacon">
```

so that, when submitted, query parameters get passed like (if both boxes are ticked) `breakfast=eggs&breakfast=bacon`.  The CGI specification states that this should be interpreted as an array or list of values, and this technique is also useful for dynamically-sized lists of inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="url">
<input type="button" value="More…"
       onclick="var s = document.createElement('input');
                s.type='text';
                s.name='url';
                this.form.appendChild(s);
                return false;">
```

However, I can see no way to get list-valued inputs from a form in Yesod.  Is there any way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the prebuilt fields work on inputs with a single input (with a notable exception for multiSelectField). To achieve what you're looking for, you probably want to create a custom [Field](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/1.0.0.4/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Types.html#t%3aField). Notice that the `fieldParse` function takes a list of `Text` values, specifically to allow your use case.

The [chapter on forms](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms) includes a section on custom fields.