# Array of Checkboxes in Yesod

Tags: haskell, checkbox, checkboxlist, yesod

I would like to create an array of checkboxes in a Yesod Form and get back the answer as Bools (in a list, tuple, or something like that).

This question: [Dynamically-Sized List of Fields in Yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485186/dynamically-sized-list-of-fields-in-yesod) seems to indicate that I need to create a custom field, but the explanation of how to do this in the Yesod Book: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms is a little sparse and I can't quite figure out how to build it from there.

Can someone provide a working example of how to put together this kind of form element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesod.Form 1.3.3 added `checkboxesFieldList`, which provides this functionality.